# I'm using python eval and ran into a problem

Tags: python

```
Ship = ["1번 배","2번 배","3번 배","4번 배"]
global Player0
Player0 = {'Money':10,'Ship':0}
global Player1
Player1 = {'Money':10,'Ship':0}
global Player2
Player2 = {'Money':10,'Ship':0}
global Player3
Player3 = {'Money':10,'Ship':0}

for i in range(4):
    SelectShip = int(input("베팅할 배의 번호를 입력하세요 : "))
    BetMoney = int(input("베팅할 금액을 입력하세요 : "))

    SelectShip += 1

    eval('Player%d["Money"] = Player%d["Money"]-BetMoney'%(i,i))
    eval('Player%d["Ship"] = SelectShip' %i)




    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\holay\PycharmProjects\합법토토\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    eval('Player%d["Money"] = int(Player%d["Money"])-BetMoney'%(i,i))
  File "<string>", line 1
    Player0["Money"] = int(Player0["Money"])-BetMoney
                     ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried to assign a value to a dictionary using python's eval , but it failed and I've been thinking about this for 3 days. Please help
I don't know why this error occurs. Experts please help TT.TT

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is for expressions, e.g. `"x+1"`, what you want to use is `exec`, which is for statements.

Having said that, there are **definitely better ways than using either eval or exec**. Instead of defining four variables Player0 - Player3, define a list `Players` and just use code like `Players[i]["Money"] -= BetMoney`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [`eval()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74110358/im-using-python-eval-and-ran-into-a-problem) function for statements. Instead use [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) for dynamic execution of python code.